# Swift and autolayout: proportional font size in a label

Tags: text, swift, label, size, autolayout

I have a storyboard with (among other things) a label. Its height is proportional to the screen height. But the text size in the label is always the same. I'd like to also have a proportional font size.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Maybe I should specify that my label has both width and height proportional to the screen size (the bigger the screen is, the bigger the label is).

I did it programmatically but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it from the storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

click the label and choose the size properties inspector on the right hand side and edit the font size. You can then choose a size of your choosing

Comment: I know how to change the size of a text label but I don't know how to adapt its size with the autolayout to have a text size proportional to the screen size. For example, on a 4S iPhone I'd like a text size of 18, on a 5 iPhone a size of 20, on a 5S iPhone a size of 22, etc.